# XSLT equivalent for XBRL that allows transformations on XBRL like XSLT does to XML

Tags: java, python, perl, export-to-csv, xbrl

Is there an XSLT equivalent for XBRL? Something to allow me to do transformations on XBRL like XSLT does to XML. Another option would be a java/python program/perl or other easy to learn program that is open source and can run on Linux Ubuntu that would convert from XBRL to csv files in batch.

Answer (score 6):

The [*eXtensible Business Reporting Language* (XBRL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL) is just a standard that says how to use XML documents and how they should be structured. XSLT will transform XBRL just fine because it is XML data.

Comment: Apologies, Borodin, I meant to upvote your answer, not downvote, but I don't manage to undo it as it says it's locked. Even though I put it in perspective, I believe that your answer is accurate technically, especially from a pragmatic and practical viewpoint, as XML tools are currently at a very high level of maturity and XBRL tools are more recent. If you do a tiny edit, I should be able to fix my vote if I understood how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the closest to a transformation language in XBRL would be [XBRL Formula 1.0](http://www.xbrl.org/wgn/xbrl-formula-overview/pwd-2011-12-21/xbrl-formula-overview-wgn-pwd-2011-12-21.html), also standardized by XBRL international.

The XBRL data model (which is to distinguish from the underlying XML syntax, which is a different, tree-based and semi-structured data model) involves facts reported against concepts and carrying contexts (period, entity, unit, dimensions). Transforming XBRL to XBRL means transforming input instance facts to output instance facts, and this is exactly what XBRL Formula does.

This is analogous to XSLT transforming XML documents into new XML documents.

Transforming XBRL into something *else* than XBRL is best done with an XBRL processor (some of them allow exporting instance facts as well as taxonomies to tabular/csv formats via APIs). XSLT itself, as suggested by Borodin, works as well on the underlying XML syntax, but may lead to semantic errors in the output, as XSLT is not aware of the XBRL data model.